# DataTable to observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, observablecollection

I have been googling and searching for the answers here, but I still fail to understand a very basic thing - How to convert a DataTable to an Observable Collection?

This is how far I've gotten:

```
public ObservableCollection<Test> test;

public class Test
{
    public int id_test { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Main..

```
 DataTable TestTable = new DataTable();
 TestTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id_test", typeof(int)));
 TestTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)));
 DS.Tables.Add(TestTable);


var test = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
        foreach(DataRow row in test_table.Rows)
     {
         var obj = new Test()
    {
        id_test = (int)row.ItemArray[0],
        name = (string)row.ItemArray[1]

    };
        test.Add(obj);
```

I updated the code and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to create a new collection for each row in the table, but rather one collection for the entire table (with one object in the collection created for one row in the table):

```
var test = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
foreach(var row in TestTable.Rows)
{
    var obj = new Test()
    {
        id_test = (int)row["id_test"],
        name = (string)row["name"]
    };
    test.Add(obj);
}
```

Comment: oh my, silly me you are right. But are you sure that the code above works? There is a huge chance that I have missed something, but 1)problem it doesn't recognize "name"

Comment: @boo_boo_bear I tried to use the same column and property names as you did in your question - maybe there is a difference between the code in your project and what you originally posted? What exact error are you getting?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated the code in the question, it's working. I know I shouldn't be asking other questions in comment section, but I have no idea how to bind it properly. It doesn't add anything to the ComboBoxColumn

Comment: @boo_boo_bear yw :) You can always ask another question if you are encountering another problem.

Comment: The semicolon after after the first variable assignment in new Test() needs to be a comma, and the semicolon after the second variable assignment needs to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I had a little issue with the accepted solution.  It does not allow the [] brackets on type var.

```
var test = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
foreach(DataRow row in TestTable.Rows)
{
    test.Add(new Test()
    {
        id_test = (int)row["id_test"],
        name = (string)row["name"],
     });
 }
```

Comment: Remove comma after the last variable assignment in the new Test declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use this ObservableCollection to bind to a WPF control and get change notifications then it may be unnecessary to make the DataTable > ObservableCollection conversion. Some built-in WPF controls such as `System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid` **already provides change notification mechanism when bound to a DataTable**. For instance, when you add, update or delete rows in the source DataTable, the DataGrid will reflect these changes automatically. Example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelPropertyAsDataTable}"/>
```

Some third party controls like Telerik RadGridView, on the other hand, use the *DataTable.DefaultView property* to provide change notifications. Example:

```
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelPropertyAsDataTable.DefaultView}"/>
```