# DevExpress WPF GridControl with dynamic columns and rows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I'm working with a DevExpress 14.1 GridControl on WPF, which must bind to a dynamic source. We don't know the number of columns or rows on design time, so this must be calculated on the fly.

The source may be changed while executing, adding more rows, or columns, or BOTH (I could have a table with 3 columns and 5 rows, and a 6th row with 4 columns could be inserted, adding a new column to the model with empty data for the previous rows).

I was using a DataTable as ItemsSource for the grid, but it will only load data inserted on design time. If I add columns while running the app, the grid wont update for some reason.

Is there an observable object that can satisfy this needs?

Answer (score 0):

It's using code-behind (not MVVM) and maybe you already tried it, but have you tried explicitly calling `myGrid.RefreshData()` in your .xaml.cs file?  There'd be some hook-ups to get it to call at the right times depending on your data changes, but it might at least help you narrow in on the problem if it helps or not.

DevExpress support answer [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T211767) may help also.

Changing from a DataTable to an ObservableCollection may also do the trick: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759603/datatable-to-observable-collection).

BTW, I've found DevExpress's support ticket system to be very helpful; they seem to respond within ~24 hours for issues and questions.  If you're still able to get support for your license & can't solve it still, I'd ask them the same question [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).